# Method setX() with type int not found on target class class android.view.View

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I am creating an animation for my Android app using android Property Animation.
I create an XML file in `res/animator/ directory`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set android:ordering="sequentially" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:duration="500"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="400"
        android:valueType="intType"/>
</set>
```

I inflate the XML resources in your code to an AnimatorSet object using `AnimatorInflater`.

```
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(PropertyAnimationActivity.this,
            R.animator.animation_load_from_xml_example);
            set.setTarget(animatorSetView);
            set.start();
```

I get error

> PropertyValuesHolder: Method setX() with type int not found on target
>   class class android.view.View

Any idea how to fix the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your valueType to `android:valueType="floatType"` as setX() takes an float value ([ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX(float))).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `android:propertyName="translationX"` property, because you use both valueFrom and valueTo, which means move view from x1 to x2, I guess. If you want use property x then you should only valueTo property.